# Symfony2 delete memcached key on logout

Tags: symfony, memcached, logout

How can I delete key from `memcached` on logout in `Symfony2` without writing custom handler? Sorry for my english. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers are not hard!
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html

So, you have to do the following:

1. Find the event you need to bind to
2. Create an EventListener class (with just one method "onLogout")
3. Add an entry to services.yml where you bind the eventListener method to the event

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Only with writing custom handler. What problem with it?